# Windows not booting

Tags: boot, windows

my windows won't boot after I installed ubuntu 17. It shows a message about resizing partitions. I have tried to upgrade grub through ubuntu, I installed gparted on ubuntu and still nothing.

Comment: Please edit and paste the exact error massage you're getting

Comment: There were 2 releases of Ubuntu in 2017, one in April (17.04) and another in October (17.10), so we're assuming you mean 17.10 so please tell us if you don't mean Ubuntu 17.10.  Try running `disks`  (`gnome-disks` from terminal) or your `gparted` (which does nothing until you tell it to run) and see if you can see your Windows partitions.  (this is to ensure its there, that you didn't select 'use entire disk')  I have no idea what you mean by "message about resizing partitions" so as @Félicien has already asked - please add (via edit) the message so we can help you with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)

Answer (score 2):

Although this question should be asked in Windows forums. I hope you haven't installed Ubuntu on the same drive as Windows. But if you have then you may have some master boot record issues, but if you want your windows to boot normally as it did before, Try this:

## Repairing a Windows partition on a dual-boot PC

Install a separate hard drive or prepare a separate partition for each operating system.

Install the operating systems. For example, if your PC has Windows 10, install Ubuntu 17 onto the other hard drive or partition.

Reboot the PC. The boot menus should appear with both operating systems listed.

If both operating systems aren't listed:

Open a command line, either as an administrator from inside Windows, or by booting to a command line using the Windows installation disk and presssing Shift+F10, or by booting to Windows Recovery disk.

Add boot options for a Windows operating system.

```
Bcdboot C:\Windows
```

Reboot the PC. Now, the boot menu will show both menu options.

Try listing the disks active by:

```
diskpart
list disk
```

If the type is MBR, type:

```
sel disk C
```

press Enter.
In this case, C is the drive where Windows folder was found. If the Windows folder is on a different drive, use that drive letter instead of “C” in the sel disk command above.

```
list vol
sel vol C
```

In this case, C is the drive where Windows folder was found. If the Windows folder is on a different drive, use that drive letter instead of “C” in the sel disk command above.

```
Type: active and press Enter
```

You should get a confirmation that the volume has been successfully set as active. If you don’t get the confirmation, it means that either the disk is set to GPT (not MBR), or there is a problem with the disk. Make sure you are working with the right disk.

```
Type: exit and press Enter
```

Reboot the device - you can do this quickly from the command prompt by typing:

`shutdown -f -r -t 00 and press Enter`

[image: dispart-select-disk-windows]
[image]
Do Not Attempt to do clean disk or convert it as it will wipe it off!

Let us know how it goes, What error message were you getting in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Use boot repair :

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

This will fix the dualboot.

Comment: This is a copy of [an answer to the possible-duplicate question](https://askubuntu.com/a/921722/250300). If an answer of another question can be applied, please flag the question as a duplicate and do not answer it.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to my Windows not booting after installing Ubuntu, I was seeing a countdown and then a message about using GParted, easybcd and a Windows CD to solve the problem. As instructed by Windows:

1. Insert the Windows disc or Windows bootable USB.
2. Then clicked on Repair my computer.
3. Clicked Troubleshoot
4. Advanced options
5. CMD
6. Typed the following:

   ```
   bootsect /nt60 SYS /force
   ```
7. I then restarted my PC and booted into Windows with no issues. Ubuntu works fine as well.

Comment: This will damage the Ubuntu boot.. So its not recommend.

Comment: How will it damage windows, please explain. This is an instructional message from windows itself! How can it damage the computer!